# Android showing "Unable to get system library for project"

Tags: android

I was working on an android tutorial and it wanted me to import the library from another project. All well and good. The import worked and the project works correctly. But I noticed that doing that messed up several of my other projects (the ones that use Android 2.2) by apparently messing with the build path. Now instead of seeing "Google APIs [Android 2.2]" under the gen folder I see "Unable to get system library for project". When I right-click the project and go to Properties I see that the correct Project Build Target is checked(Google APIs [Android 2.2]), but "Unable to get system library for project" is still shown above the assets folder and below gen and Android Dependencies. Cleaning all projects doesn't help. How can I fix this problem, and is there a way to fix this issue globally or do I have to do it one by one?

Comment: you would need to set dependencies in Eclipse -> Preferences -> Android

Comment: ok, that's weird. I closed and reopened Eclipse and everything's all good. It looks like that reset the dependencies maybe?

Comment: haha sure. Eclipse is quite buggy imo. Glad it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the project root folder you should have file named project.properties

---- file  content -----

target=android-16 ## <--- make sure that it is there and that you have proper sdk installed

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that in the Project settings - Android tab, I had no Android version selected.

Answer (score 0):

For me I had SDK version 8 selcted, but if I selected the next highest version, applied, then selected version 8 again and apply, fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, what worked was to restart Eclipse. Hope this helps.